# how to update product.wxs file dynamic

Tags: .net, wix, wix3, dynamic, screensaver

i want to make an application which includes dynamic screensaver. User can select multiple images from their PC and generate swf file. so i want to include swf file and images in the wix project dynamically. and want to generate an MSI file.is there any way to add images path and swf file dynamically

reply me soon

Samir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wxs file is just XML. You can edit it in your application with any XML API. In .NET, you can do this by loading the file in a [System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28VS.71%29.aspx) or [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use the heat.exe tool included in wix to "harvest" (i.e. generate a wxs file for) individual files or an entire folder. This doesn't allow you to edit a wxs file exactly, but that is not a problem because a wix setup can consist of multiple wxs files.

From the [heat.exe documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm):

> **Harvest a file**
>
> ```
> heat file -ag -template:fragment -out file.wxs ".\My Files\File.dll"
> ```
>
> This will harvest the file "File.dll"
>   as a single fragment to the file
>   file.wxs. The component guid will be
>   set to "*".